# Mercurial, detect merge conflicts

Tags: bash, merge, mercurial

I want to create a bash script that periodically merges my default branch into all active branches. When a merge conflict occurs, the script should skip the branch and rollback any changes.

To achieve this I figure I need to detect if a conflict occurs. Is there a way to detect conflicts before merging? Something like a hg detect-conflicts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hg merge --tool internal:merge` to attempt a merge using Mercurials internal merging tools (so no vimdiff etc.)
Then use `hg resolve --list` to see if you have any conflicts.

> $ hg resolve --list
>
> U conflicted.file

If this is the case, you can use `hg update -C .` to revert back to the revision before the merge.